# Append string to the end of a JSON request in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I am trying to append data data from a form to a request so that the complete URL is sent as the request. I know I can do this in PHP but want to know if I can also do it in the javascript
 For example the  json request is sent to

```
"http://api.wunderground.com/api/myapi/conditions/q/ZIP.json"
```

Where ZIP will be replaced by the user submission

```
 $(function() {
 $("#getzip").submit(function() {
   var zip_data =$(this).serialize();
    $.getJSON("get_weather.php",null , function(data); {
```

Is it possible to pass it in stead of the null? And how would I go about appending it to the request strictly in the javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you would need to append it to the URL string itself:

```
$.getJSON("http://api.wunderground.com/api/myapi/conditions/q/" 
+ zip_data, function(data){ return data });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.getJSON("get_weather.php",{
  whatever: "value",
  somemore: "another value"
}.function(){
  //
};
```

then in your PHP:

```
$whatever=filter_input(INPUT_GET,"whatever",FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$somemore=filter_input(INPUT_GET,"somemore",FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```